# How can I set up an offbrand display link (Trulink) to work with arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules, xrandr, display, displaylink

I recently bought a USB to DVI adapter and it works great in Windows.

However, I wanted to use it on Arch since that's where I do most of my work.

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I've installed all the packages, added `udl`, and blacklisted `udlfb` as directed by the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink).

However when I run `xrandr --listproviders` it returns this:

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload       crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

Furthermore `dmesg` shows this for the USB device:

```
[ 1905.126686] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 1905.254243] usb-storage 2-1:2.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1905.254552] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1:2.0
[ 1906.258054] scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
[ 1906.258075] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM                                              PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1906.261289] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 8x/40x writer xa/form2 cdda tray
[ 1906.261747] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
```

It looks to me like it thinks my display device is a USB-storage device.

EDIT:
I just now found out that the device mounts as a storage device with the drivers on it.  I guess this would explain why it says it's a storage device, but it still doesn't help me solve the real problem.

So, my questions are:

- Is there a way I can fool it into loading the correct driver/kernel module for it?  I think the display link driver will work with it, if I can just find a way to have arch load it.
- Do I need to do something in the Xorg config?

Also in case it's relevant:

- My window manager is xfce4
- I'm trying to set up a third monitor
- I have an Intel graphics card